# Incomprehensible error with babel and isodate

Tags: memoir, babel, date, isodate

The error in question is:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
\ifthenelse #1#2#3->\let \bbl@temp@pref 
                                    \pageref \let \pageref \org@pageref 
...
l.19 \date{\today}
```

Code:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[english]{isodate}
\begin{document}
\isodate
\date{\today}
\end{document}
```

Intention:

I would like for `\thedate` to not print e.g. `September 10. 2018` but rather `2018-09-10`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I tested your example with all versions of TeX Live from 2012 to 2018. Up to 2014 the error is different, but still the code doesn't work.

This is because `memoir` has a different definition of `\date` than the standard classes. It performs `\protected@xdef` on the argument to `\date` in order to define `\thedate` so that footnotes or `\thanks` commands disappear from it and this is the problem: `isodate` redefines `\today` in such a way that it doesn't survive `\protected@xdef`.

You solve the issue with

```
\date{\protect\today}
```

Comment: So what does the error actually mean? I am getting the same error in beamer, using pgfplots and explicitely calling `visualizaion depends on={value \ifthenelse{\thisrow{v}<90}{white}{black} \as \tcolor}` which throws the above error and I have no idea how to debug this. Is there some straight-forward solution or do I have to post a separate question?

Comment: @BjarneThorsted A separate question is in order with more details.

Comment: I have created a question, [Obscure error with conditional formatting in pgfplots](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/464287/obscure-error-with-conditional-formatting-in-pgfplots)