# Obscure error with conditional formatting in pgfplots

Tags: pgfplots

I am trying to format a matrix plot in such a way that the nodes will change text color depending on the cell color. This is turning out to be a lot more complicated than I expected.

The following code gets stuck somehow at the `\ifthenelse` command and I have no idea how to get it running properly.

```
% contents of matrix.txt
x   y   v
0   0   78
1   0   63
2   0   42
3   0   51
4   0   99
...

% MWE
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[enlargelimits=false, axis lines=none, colormap/blackwhite]
            \addplot [
                matrix plot,
                visualization depends on={value \ifthenelse{\thisrow{v} < 90}{white}{black} \as \tcolor},
                nodes near coords,
                scatter/@pre marker code/.append style={/tikz/text=\tcolor},
                mesh/cols=8,
                point meta=explicit,
                ] table [x=x, y=y, meta=v] {matrix.txt};
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: This depends on `\ifthenelse` not being expandable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As [pointed out by @egreg](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/464287/obscure-error-with-conditional-formatting-in-pgfplots#comment1168197_464287), `\ifthenelse` is not the right tool here. And there is no need to load `ifthen` because Ti*k*Z has a built-in function `ifthenelse`, which you might use as follows:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{matrix.txt}
x   y   v
1   0   63
2   0   42
3   0   51
4   0   99
1   1   63
2   1   42
3   1   51
4   1   99
\end{filecontents*}

\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[enlargelimits=false, axis lines=none, colormap/blackwhite]
            \addplot [
                matrix plot,
                visualization depends on={%
                ifthenelse(\thisrow{v}>90,100,0) \as \myv},
                nodes near coords,
                scatter/@pre marker code/.append style={/tikz/text=black!\myv},
                mesh/cols=4,mesh/rows=2,
                point meta=explicit,
                ] table [x=x, y=y, meta=v] {matrix.txt};
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That worked perfectly! Thank you so much! I can't believe how close I was to the actual solution.